# Downloading pdf from server and displaying it

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I'm trying to Downloading pdf from server and displaying it as it is.

I tried the following code snippet but it's giving me error as shown below.

I'm not able to understand why it's giving `No Activity found to handle Intent` exception.

I'm new to android so any help appreciated...

**onCreate() snippet**

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
    folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Downloader.DownloadFile(
            "http://www.nmu.ac.in/ejournals/aspx/courselist.pdf", file);

    File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/pdf/Read.pdf");
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unused" })
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pdftest/com.pdftest.PDFFromServerExample}: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/pdf/Read.pdf typ=application/pdf }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/pdf/Read.pdf typ=application/pdf }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
at com.pdftest.PDFFromServerExample.onCreate(PDFFromServerExample.java:44)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: see i have edited my answer ..might same that you want ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't provider any inbuilt Application that reads the PDF content. So, in your case you are doing as

```
typ=application/pdf
```

But there is no Application that reads or knows what this refers to. So, you have to install PDF reader which may me any that tries to link up `typ=application/pdf` and passes it to that Application to read the PDF.

Comment: So you mean that file is getting downloaded?

Comment: It seems from the error that your app is crashing somewhere in here - `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");` just debug and check it.

Comment: And for checking that your file is downloaded you can check it in the SDCard.

Comment: Well you have give path as `/pdf/Read.pdf`

Comment: so where `/pdf/Read.pdf` will be placed. I know it depends on `String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();` , but don't know the location.

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is no application that can handle a displaying a pdf, this is often times a third party application. Specifically what you are interested in is the Action of the Intent and how you can catch it and display it if possible.

Comment: So you mean that file is getting downloaded?

Comment: Downloading/displaying are two different processes, please research based on what Latit said.

Comment: I got it. I don't have any pdf reader so file is not getting displayed but how do I come to know that file is downloaded or not?

Comment: That has to be done through your download process, you need look at the frameworks/sdk and see how you can determine this.

Comment: Path specified is `Read.pdf` file withing `pdf` folder. But where this `pdf` folder is located?

Comment: Try it in an emulator and see what you find. Chances ar ewhen downloads are done through the Browser, it goes into the Downloads directory of the sdcard.

Comment: You're going to have to look yourself, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you **do not have** pdf reader though you try to read the pdf .

only thing you need to do is install the pdf reader like adobe reader or some else . this code will work fine after that !!!!

And your intention is only to view the pdf and you have internet connection then it would be fine to open your pdf in google docs , like

http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.nmu.ac.in/ejournals/aspx/courselist.pdf.

**Note:(well ..this is alternative of viewing pdf, honestly i am not recommend it  )**

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(dwonload_file_name);
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "PDF Reader application is not installed in your device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Hope it'll be helpful. [Full Source Code for "How to download file from Server"](http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/05/download-file-to-your-android-device.html)